# ADOB VBA Automation error when inserting data into table

Tags: sql, vba, excel-2010, ado

I am trying to insert a row into an excel table named DataRange2$. From the same workbook. I am getting a (Run time Automation error -214721793). My code works when I query the Excel workbook such as `select * from DataRange2$`. I want to insert a row but got this error. I am using ADOB, VBA, and excel 2010.

The SQL query being sent in is:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO [DataSheet2$] (Name, a, b, c, d, e) VALUES ('This is a name', 10, 20, 30, 40, 50)"
`Result` is the array which is populated with the returned rows 
runQuery SQL, result
```

Code:

```
Public Function runQuery(SQL As String, ByRef result() As String) As Integer
  Dim dataConection As New ADODB.connection
  Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim DBPath As String
  Dim connectionString As String
  Dim size As Integer

  Set mrs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  'Set cursor to start
  mrs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

  'Set database path
  DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName

  'You can provide the full path of your external file as shown below
  connectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

  'Open connection to database
  dataConection.Open connectionString

  'Open record set (query or table, connection)
  mrs.Open SQL, dataConection

  'Record set returned update data
  If mrs.EOF Then
      runQuery = 0
      Exit Function
  Else
      runQuery = mrs.RecordCount
  End If

  'Populate array with result
  ReDim result(size) As String
  Dim i As Integer

  For i = 0 To (size - 1)
      result(i) = mrs!Name
      mrs.MoveNext
  Next i

  'Close record set and connection
  mrs.Close
  dataConection.Close
End Function
```

The worksheet headers are as follows

```
Name | a | b | c | d | e | Status | Action
```

Comment: `Set mrs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")`  Why do this?  Why not just `Set mrs = New ADODB.RecordSet` to instantiate it?  When you step through your code, where is it failing?  I don't think the problem is in your VBA.  You might find it has to do with forms and form controls.  That's, at least, where I've run into errors like this.

Comment: The error occurs at  mrs.Open SQL, dataConection

Comment: This works for queries like select but not for insert which I thought was weird. Also I just declared createObject because the examples I saw online used that.

Comment: I can honestly say I haven’t ever used VBA to read or write to an excel file using ADODB.   Not sure where I could see a good use for that.  That being said, check permissions.

Comment: I am making a tool for my client to enter data into a external workbook. I want to use sql against the work book so I don't have to code all the sql by hand

Comment: @Jaberwocky Any ideas? i'm pretty stuck...

Comment: I have to encourage you to check permissions at the source.  You may not be able to write externally.

Comment: I have the same issue when I run this against an internal worksheet though?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176749/discussion-between-user-and-jaberwocky).

Comment: I can't help you.  Like I said, this is an application I haven't ever even attempted.  Sorry.

Comment: @Jaberwocky All good thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two functions being attempted  (1)  INSERT a new row,  and  (2) Get x rows of Names.  These require two separate ADODB.Recordset.  The following does the Insert, but fails on stepping thru the Get

```
Sub zz()
    Dim sSQL As String, sResult(3) As String
    sSQL = "INSERT INTO [DataSheet2$] (Name, a, b, c, d, e) 
            VALUES ('This is a name', 10, 20, 30, 40, 50)"
    'Result is the array which is populated with the returned rows
    runQuery sSQL, sResult
End Sub



Public Function runQuery(SQL As String, ByRef result() As String) As Integer
  Dim dataConection As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
  Dim DBPath As String
  Dim connectionString As String
  Dim size As Integer

  Set mrs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  'Set cursor to start
  mrs.CursorLocation = adUseClient

  'Set database path
  DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName

  'You can provide the full path of your external file as shown below
  connectionString = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;DSN=Excel Files;DBQ=" & DBPath & ";HDR=Yes';"

  'Open connection to database
  dataConection.Open connectionString

  'Open record set (query or table, connection)
  mrs.Open SQL, dataConection   '>> this is where the INSERT happens

  'Record set returned update data
  If mrs.EOF Then   ''>> rte 3704  Operation not allowed when object is closed
      runQuery = 0
      Exit Function
  Else
      runQuery = mrs.RecordCount
  End If

  'Populate array with result
  ReDim result(size) As String
  Dim i As Integer

  For i = 0 To (size - 1)
      result(i) = mrs!Name
      mrs.MoveNext
  Next i

  'Close record set and connection
  mrs.Close
  dataConection.Close
End Function
```

Comment: I am not home just yet but if that fixed my problem you are an angel!